# Function Argument that might or might not instantiate a TypeClass?

Tags: haskell, yesod

This is what I'm trying to make my Handler look like -

```
getUserStudentsR :: UserId -> Handler TypedContent
getUserStudentsR userId = 
      getStudentEntitiesForCoach userId 
      >>= returnTypedContent . map toUserStudentResponse
```

where Student is a Persistent Entity (details mostly not important) and

```
getStudentEntitiesForCoach :: UserId -> HandlerT App IO [Entity Student]
getStudentEntitiesForCoach coachId = 
    runDB $ selectList [StudentPrimaryCoachId ==. Just(coachId)] [] 

data UserStudentResponse = StudentResponse (Key Student) Student

instance ToJSON UserStudentResponse where
    toJSON (StudentResponse studentId student) = 
          object
                  [
                      "login" .= studentLogin student
                      , "studentId" .= studentId
                      , "firstName" .= studentFirstname student
                      , "lastName" .= studentLastname student

                  ]

toUserStudentResponse :: (Entity Student) -> UserStudentResponse
toUserStudentResponse (Entity studentId student) 
    = StudentResponse studentId student
```

and

```
returnTypedContent x = selectRep $ do 
                          provideJson x
```

Now obviously, this doesn't compile unless UserStudentResponse instantiates ToJSON and provides an implementation for toJSON. However, I want to make the returnTypedContent function generic - something like -

```
returnTypedContent x = selectRep $ do 
                         -- if ToJSON x -- 
                            provideJSON x
                         -- if ToHTML x -- -- note this is not an either or
                            provideRep $ return $ toHtml $ a
```

I want to do this, so that returnTypedContent can be expanded to provide returns for all kinds of contenttypes and then based on whether the data type used in the handler instantiates certain typeclasses (such as ToJSON), we have different things provided for.

Is something like this possible without going into Template Haskell?

Comment: I'm not really a yesod user, but what does `selectRep` do?  Isn't it sufficient to just create a `ToTypedContent` instance for `UserStudentResponse`?

Comment: You can't do that directly (modulo the chance that somebody else comes up with some clever tricks); constraints like `ToJSON [a]` are propositions, not booleans internal to the language.  Try writing down the type for `returnTypedContent`.  That will hopefully provide some insight as to why you can't do this, and possibly help design a workaround (though I don't immediately know what one would look like).

Comment: with `-XOverlappingInstances` you can make a "fallback" instance of `ToJSON` and `ToHTML`. You might be able to treat the values you get from the fallback instance specially (they could be `throw SomeVeryUniqueException`, if there's no json/html value that's normally off-limits).

You're better off writing a large number of instances with template-haskell I think.

Comment: @aavogt - I'll try fallback instances..need to read up on them now. Agree, template haskell is probably the only way to achieve this well, but I want to avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this (enable GADTs):

```
data Wrapper a where
    Json :: ToJSON a => a -> Wrapper a
    Html :: ToHTML a => a -> Wrapper a
```

and then you can pattern match:

```
returnTypedContent (Json x) = selectRep (provideJSON x)
returnTypedContent (Html x) = selectRep (provideRep $ return $ toHtml x)
```

You would have to explicitly wrap your data, but that shouldn't be too problematic.

Comment: No.. it's not an if-else.. my code needs to do both (provideJSON and provideRep) if a instantiates both ToJSON and ToHTML - that is to give Yesod the option of respondign to both type of content type requests.. in your way, if there is a instantiates ToJSON, it will never do provideRep.

Also.. there is no way I can send in a "a" that doesn't implement either ToJSON or ToHTML. Which i need to btw..

Comment: @RoopeshShenoy: You could of course extend the wrapper to also include a `Both` and `Neither` constructor. (You may be better off using the `OverlappingInstances` suggestion by @aavogt though. But I would make a separate type class for selectRep and use the overlapping there instead of on `ToJSON` and `ToHTML`.)

Comment: interesting suggestion, let me see if something like that works

Comment: @RoopeshShenoy: I've been playing around with the `OverlappingInstances` for a bit and I'm not sure that my suggestion is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. GHC currently provides no way to "match on the instance head"

So it is impossible to have

```
instance Foo a => Bar a where ...
instance Bar a where ...
```

where the dispatch chooses between them if Foo matches.

But you *can*, with closed type families, give fallthroughs in specific instances. The GHC manual demonstrates this technique: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html#closed-type-families